# Python httplib2 POST method with many data

Tags: python, post

I use httplib2 to POST https . But my script get error " 400 Bad Request : Following arguments are required: username, scope, password, client_id" . Although i pass enough params for POST. Below my script:

```
 >>> from httplib2 import Http
 >>> from urllib import urlencode
 >>> h = Http()
 >>> data = dict(client_id="x.y.z",username="user",password="xxxxxxx",scope="store",access_token_only="1",for_username="1x2xdddzz",for_credential_type="facebook")
 >>> resp, content = h.request("https://someserver.com/authorize", "POST", urlencode(data))
 >>> content
    '400 Bad Request : Following arguments are required: username, scope, password, client_id
```

'

I have searched , but don't have solution for this. If you get same the problem , please give me one solution.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Didi you try passing just the arguments required? username, scope, password, client_id

Comment: What's in the `resp` ? Do you have access to the server's log ?

Comment: @maurelio79 . I tried with 4 params username, scope, password, client_i, but it is still occurr.

Comment: @bvidal , resp : resp
{'status': '400', 'content-length': '513', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'Date', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'CherryPy/3.1.2', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Thu, 09 Jan 2014 18:07:54 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-allow-methods': '*', 'content-type': 'text/html'}

Comment: Is there any "weird" characters in the parameters you send that could truncate the data sent to the server ?

Comment: @bvidal  i'm sure data ok . Because i used add-on Poster  try to post with this data, It is posted to server success . I worry so this error relate to httplib2

Comment: If you think that this might come form httplib2 then try the `requests` module http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ which is fairly easy to use.

Comment: i will read it to find a solution . Thanks